# Get a secuence from a string using regular expressions #Python #Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I would like your help using #Python.

I have this dataset:

```
E   1   1999-02-28  b,g,f    jjj:12,bbb:3,ddd:9,ggg:8,hhh:2
A   2   1999-10-28  a,f,c,d  ccc:2,ddd:0,aaa:3,hhh:9
```

I need to get the secuence b,g,f and a,f,c,d in a list.
I tried using many combinations of the pattern [a-z],[a-z], but every time the last term is skipped, I do not know how to generalize to get the sequence.

The output should look like this:

```
[b,g,f]
[a,f,c,d]
```

The dataset comes from a csv file, I'm reading like this:

```
with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Then using a for loop to read the lines:

```
list_sequence = []
for i in lines:
    a = re.findall(pattern= '???' , string=str(i))
    list_sequence.append(b)
```

In the question marks, is where I need to find the pattern.

Comment: Is that a part of a Pandas dataframe? What code yields incomplete results? Please share.

Comment: The idea is not use pandas, just get the pattern using regular expressions.

Comment: So, share your current code please. Also, it is possible to do that without regex.

Comment: The dataset comes from a csv file:

Comment: So, what `pattern= '???'` did you use?

Comment: This is what I do not know, nothing works.

Comment: But you say "*I tried using many combinations of the pattern [a-z],[a-z], but every time the last term is skipped*" - what was it that skipped something?

Comment: If you use the pattern [a-z],[a-z], for example. You get the answer: ['b,g'], ['a,f', 'c,d']. Which is not correct, in the first line is skipped the letter f, it should be ['b,g,f'].

Comment: I still do not see why regex is required, see https://ideone.com/1fc1UU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)[a-z](?:,[a-z])*(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Gy59q/1/). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - left whitespace boundary
- `[a-z](?:,[a-z])*` - a lowercase ASCII letter and then zero or more sequences of a comma and a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?!\S)`  - right whitespace boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - (split each line to fields and split the forth field once again)

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
  data = []
  for line in f:
    parts = line.split()
    data.append(parts[3].split(','))
print(data)
```

output

```
[['b', 'g', 'f'], ['a', 'f', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: If I split by commas, it should take just the first letter of the sequence.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos Did you try my solution? It seems to work..

Comment: It works, but I would like to find the answer using regex.